# How do I extract text and formatting from a ppt file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, text-parsing

I'm trying to write a context-sensitive text parser in python. To do that, I need to be able to open ppt files and extract both the text and information about how it was formatted. I need to be able to tell if a sentence was in a header or if it's bolded, for instance.

It's supposed to run on large batches of files, so manually converting all the ppts to pptxs isn't practical. 
I tried tika, but it doesn't give formatting information.
I tried python-pptx, but it doesn't seem like it can open ppts.
And I'm hoping to make the parser OS agnostic, so the command-line converters I've seen proposed on other variants of this question won't work for me, unless they'll somehow work on linux, mac, and windows.